# My answer to my own question was deleted. Why?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702000/367677) and then [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711149/367677) it. After quite a long time the answer got deleted by a moderator and I do not understand the reason for that.

FAQ lists the following possibilities (my replies **in bold**):

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers - **it's not**
> - asking another, different question - **it's not**
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses - **it's not**
> - exact duplicates of other answers - **this** *could* **be the reason at the first glance, but I would disagree as my answer contains some extra details that actually solved my problem and provides a full code snippet**
> - barely more than a link to an external site - **it's not**
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question - **it's not**

Why did this happen?

Comment: A quick look tells me it's because it was all code and no explanation.

Comment: @yoda Your English has improved!

Comment: @yoda, seems heavy-handed to me: It was deleted 18 month after it was posted by a mod that (according to tags) has no Android experience. Hopefully it was just an error and it'll be rectified.

Comment: @CosminPrund Mods don't judge correctness of answers, so having tag experience is immaterial. Any way, I'm sure a mod will take a look at this. You can also flag it for attention.

Comment: Sheesh, there was a different answer there that should have been the one deleted. (It's been made a comment now.)

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: if that's really the case - should it be undeleted?

Comment: @Asahi, now that I read your answer, is there anything in your answer that's not already in Zulaxia's answer? It seems to me like the root of the problem was the use of `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight`, and that was already mentioned in the other answer, a good 24 hours before your own. If there really is something in your answer that's not in the other answer, you should have mentioned it.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, yes, I wrote it is as a comment to Zulaxia's answer. Perhaps, I should have mentioned it in the answer itself

Comment: Wow, deleted? That's absurd. Thanks for posting it here. Meta likes deleting stuff, but that doesn't make it right

Comment: @jalf Dude, we have no power to delete random SO answers, it was deleted by one of your moderators. Is this going to be a regular thing with you? I promise we don't get together in MSO headquarters to storm SO deleting every post we can find; I don't quite know how you got that impression

Comment: @Asahi, I now find our moderator's decision just. There's a reason why "a wall of code" alone is not considered a good answer and you just found out why: your answer only adds something if you take into account your comment to the other answer! The answer wasn't "stand-alone", it wasn't enough by itself. You should probably simply post a new answer, this time with a proper explanation, not just the wall of code.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: [Or he can edit the deleted answer and flag it for undeletion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123806/let-users-know-that-they-can-flag-to-get-their-deleted-answers-reinstated-after)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, as a user that's what I'd do, I'd re-post a corrected answer. Flagging for mod attention just puts more work on the mods.

Comment: It's just one more flag out of the hundreds we get a day. No big deal.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I don't believe I accused you, or other "ordinary" MSO users of this. is it going to be a regular thing with you that you miscosntrue what I say as an attack on you, when nothing of the sort was intended? ;) But I don't draw a sharp line between moderators and MSO users either. If MSO wants certain content deleted, they will elect moderators who feel the same way. And moderators tend to be prominent MSO users

Comment: Maybe because you didn't Accept your own answer - this way it looks like you were just suggesting something rather than solving your own problem.

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard: thought of that too. But then I would expect this to appear on FAQ list, also I did write that this solved the problem

Comment: @Asahi not really, it's pretty much common sense - if you post solution to your own problem, it should be marked as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Didn't notice you did mark it as accepted - then guess what Marc said in his answer is what made the post get deleted after probably being flagged.

Comment: @Asahi: I notice you still haven't cleaned up your answer. How does the wall of code help future readers? Please explain _why_ the wall of code solved the problem.

Comment: @CosminPrund I have to second Bolt's decision here.  Unless your second answer deviates tremendously from the first (as in, it's a different answer, not just a greatly expounded upon answer), it should be an edit to the original answer.  Moderator capacity is not an issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've undeleted it, but! I suspect the main problem here was that it seemed to take the core elements of another answer, and then accept your own. Neither of which *individually* is a bad thing - it is entirely reasonable to accept your own answer, and entirely reasonable to expand on existing answers (maybe as an edit, depending on the nature of the change). *Personally*, I'd have accepted the other answer, which I suspect pointed you most of the way.

Answer (score 21):

[Marc's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124602/140951) is very good, and very accurate, but here's the official blow-by-blow (having been the mod to delete your answer):

Your answer was flagged with a custom mod message. Without going into the details of the  message, it indicated that you had copied code from another answer.

So I took a look at your answer.  While I can't tell exactly whether or not you copied/intended to copy the code, the code that was in your answer fully encompassed the code that was in the *other* answer that was referenced.

Granted, this could have been serendipity, you might not have looked at your question and answers before posted your answer, but without knowing that information, this is the best we have to go on.  Your code *is* a copy (with additions) of the other answer, and it was posted a *full day* after the first answer was posted.

That in itself usually isn't enough, but there's more.

Moving on, [your answer as it was viewed at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3711149/2) was comprised *completely of code* (ok, there was the statement of "This does it:" but that's not really of value).  While this might have been the case, this very much puts it in the "Very Low Quality" category.  Just like [link-only answers are not really answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), code snippets which have no context around them (or in them in the form of code comments) have just as little context.  People looking at that answer still have to work to understand what fixed it.

The original [answer referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702533/50776), however, *did* provide that context, talking about the how (left and right padding, along with a code sample) as well as an added little bonus of why density independent pixels were being used.

Finally, the code was copied (again, could be serendipity, but that is not what seemed to be the case) and proper attribution was not given, as is required by the CC-wiki license.

So, given all of these things:

1. Fairly apparent copying of existing answer
2. Lack of context around the answer
3. Lack of attribution for point 1
4. No loss of value/content because of point 1

Your answer was deleted.

That said, the [current revision of your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3711149/3) is an improvement on the prior revisions, but I'd recommend that you work on distinguishing your answer from the (now) accepted answer, as it seems your solution is focused more on the nested `LinearLayout` element.  Doing so would help detract flags from other users that see the answer in the future.

Additionally, if the accepted answer really *did* help you and you used that as a basis, you should attribute that answer properly in yours, by providing a link to it and indicating it that it was a basis.