# Should answers deleted by moderators that have been modified to comply be allowed to be reinstated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let users know that they can flag to get their deleted answers reinstated after editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123806/let-users-know-that-they-can-flag-to-get-their-deleted-answers-reinstated-after)

So a while back I asked a question about Sentiment Analysis tools for .NET. It turns out this was a rather *extensive* topic onto itself that would not garner a 5 sentance answer. It is based on the field of Natural Language Processing and entire companies are created to make quality SA tools and APIs.

However at the time of my question I did not know this, so it sat around for a while. After about 6 weeks of research on the topic, I decided to blog about Sentiment Analysis Processing Solutions for .NET. It was a rather lengthy article that I spent a lot of time with (there is ***no*** advertising on my blog as a side FYI). Once complete I decided to go back to my original post and provide the link to my article to my original question and marked is as the answer.

A few months later my answer was deleted by a moderator stating in an email the "May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?" section of the FAQ and telling me about good advertising rates on SO.

No way that was not my motive at all! I genuinely wanted to help future readers, but thought copying and pasting everything from my blog onto the SO question was redundant so I just provided the link.

OK I get it - on SO just proving links is frowned upon and I am cool with that. So I went back and modified my answer heavily to give a synopsis of my findings just in case a reader did not want to click on the link and needed a quick view of the answer.

However after the edits, my answer could not be reinstated when I clicked 'undelete'. It just told me the moderator that deleted it and had a link to inquiry if I wanted to know why it was deleted.

**I want to know if it would be possible to have a mechanism in place so that after modifying a deleted answer to conform to SO standards, can it please be undeleted, even if it was originally deleted by a moderator?** In the spirit of SO and being an evolving knowledge base that constantly improves, can people have *improved* answers reinstated?

Post in question here:
[Looking for information on a Sentiment Analysis algorithm / tool for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353193/looking-for-information-on-a-sentiment-analysis-algorithm-tool-for-net)

Comment: This is *precisely why* I posted a feature request to [let users know that they can flag to get their deleted answers reinstated after editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123806/let-users-know-that-they-can-flag-to-get-their-deleted-answers-reinstated-after) :)

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your suggestion. In my case I did not create a new answer to bypass the deleted answer, but rather just modify it.

Answer (score 6):

I've undeleted the answer for you.

You're usually supposed to raise a flag requesting review and undeletion after you edit your answer, but not enough people know that because the system doesn't really indicate it. I've posted a feature request to address this, which is linked in my comment above, and which I really hope gets implemented because this is often a problem for users and an inconvenience for us.

Comment: Fantastic that will help future readers. Can at least the current work around you suggest be added to the FAQ under the section about deleted answers until something more formal is created so that people know how to request review?

Comment: Not sure about that... perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this (if you didn't know you could flag for undeletion) would have simply been to post a new answer that complies with [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022).

People who don't know about answer quality standards are unlikely to know about the flagging link; I don't remember ever encountering a flag that said *"My answer was substandard, so I edited it to improve it; could you please undelete it now?"*

But adding signs that direct users to the "flag for moderator attention" link, [when they have already failed to read the instructions for posting a quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), seems a bit... pointless.

Comment: Funnily enough I've just undeleted an answer on Programmers where the poster did exactly this.