# Should I edit my deleted answer or add another answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, deleted-answers

I recently answered a question in haste by posting a link to the answer on my blog.  Before I had a chance to come back and expand on my answer, it was deleted by a mod.  I would really like a chance to post a well-written answer.  Should I edit my deleted answer or add a new one?

Comment: Related: [Let users know that they can flag to get their deleted answers reinstated after editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123806/let-users-know-that-they-can-flag-to-get-their-deleted-answers-reinstated-after)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should edit your answer and flag it for the moderator attention, mentioning that, `I have edited the answer, kindly un-delete it`.