# Why don't moderators say why they have deleted an answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

Meta question:

Why don't moderators say in a comment why they are deleting an answer?  (The comment would on the deleted answer, which can be seen by the poster.)  Why don't they *have* to say why?  There seems to be little value to the poster to have something deleted with no clue as to why.

Specific question:

Why did @Flexo delete [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959832/build-zlib-failed-in-mac-os/17959871#17959871)?  (Only moderators and 10K+ users will be able to see the deleted answer there.)

Comment: Your answer was a comment. It was "me too", and did not provide anything helpful.

Comment: No, I added the comment after the answer was deleted.  And the comment is obviously not deleted so I must not be talking about that!  The answer was an answer.  Can you not see it grayed out?  The previous comment here says that 10K+ users will be able to see it.

Comment: If moderators would have to leave comments explaining why on each and every action, that would significantly increase the workload. You can always come here and ask.

Comment: Oded pretty much explained what I meant. Anyway, for <10K users on SO here is a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8CB5K.png

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd is indicating that your answer should have been a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Also, if you disagree with the deletion you can always flag, choose "Other" and ask to undelete and/or explain why it was deleted in the first place. The mod handling the flag can explain with a custom message.

Comment: How was my answer "me too"??  My answer was complete and correct.  In fact the user _did_ have another libtool installed.  They reinstalled and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks @ShaWizDowArd -- I didn't know about the flag thing.

Comment: @MarkAdler a formulation such as *"The most likely cause would be that you have another libtool installed. Check that...etc."* might not have run into such issues.

Comment: "You must have another libtool installed." says the same thing, but even stronger.  It was not likely, but rather certain.

Comment: I'm still missing how my answer says "me too".

Comment: "Works for me" is the same as "me too". The only possibly useful part is "You must have another libtool installed", but it's far from being a complete answer.

Comment: Not really "me too" IMHO @MarkAdler. But in its formulation I can understand it's a bit too "no-repro" and thereby more a comment than an answer. Extend it a bit and you'll have no such troubles.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the question.  "Works for me" in this case means _not_ me too.  The configure and make _didn't_ work for him, but _did_ work for me.

Comment: I would be happy to extend the answer had that been suggested in a comment.  The "moderator" could have exercised moderation and done that, instead of summarily deleting the answer.

Comment: Anyway, from the comments it looks like you did put the OP on the right path. If you can take the comments and edit the answer to explain what exactly was the problem and how the OP solved it, you can flag the answer for undeletion.

Comment: I can edit a deleted answer?

Comment: Oh, I can edit a deleted answer.

Comment: Yes you can. And once done you can flag it for moderator attention, asking for undeletion.

Answer (score 9):

Seriously? That one liner is something that should have been a comment.

It has been flagged by multiple users as such and acted on by the moderator (rightly so, too).

Now, there were lots of *useful* comments on that answer **that should have been rolled into it** but have not.

> Why don't they have to say why?

With the amount of flags moderators have to deal with on a daily basis on a site the size of Stack Overflow, they would simply *never* be able to get through them if they had to comment each time they handled a flag. Having said that, we are looking at changes that will include delete reasons - these may or may not end up being user visible if implemented.

Also see these related posts:

- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)
- [Are Stack Overflow mods spending enough time evaluating each flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185247/are-stack-overflow-mods-spending-enough-time-evaluating-each-flag/187632#187632)

Comment: The "one liner" was a complete answer, and as was verified, a correct answer.  So how is that not an answer?

Comment: Where does one see that it was flagged by multiple users?

Comment: @Mark only moderators can see that.

Comment: @MarkAdler It wasn't complete at all. The user asked for help on how to solve the problem. Your answer did not suggest a solution. It just suggested a possible cause, but not how to fix it. Installing the right libtool was just implied. As Oded points out, the solution was only found through the comments (which should have been in your answer in the first place).

Comment: And I provided help by identifying the problem.  The OP solved the problem in short order after that.  Sounds like help to me.  As you noted, the solution to having the wrong libtool installed is obvious -- you install the right libtool.  Identifying the cause of a problem is usually 90% of the way to fixing it.

Comment: @MarkAdler - Sure. But as a high quality, detailed answer it falls short (no pun intended).

Comment: In any case I  S P E L L E D   O U T   T H E  S O L U T I O N  in the edited answer.

Comment: @MarkAdler I undeleted the answer. But for the record: all the questions in the comments asking for clarification and version information and such should have been asked as comments to the *question* **before** an answer was given. The answer then should have been "you got the wrong libtool installed. You need XY. Do blah to install it".

Comment: I didn't need the clarification in the comments to know that the problem was the wrong libtool installed.  So I didn't need to ask any questions to provide that answer.