# Correct Flagging Incentive

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, helpful-flags

I use flagging to make stackoverflow better. I have 30+ helpful flags.
It would be nice if there was a small incentive to flag bad questions so that the site gets cleaned up a little. Even if it is +1, only for helpful tags or even only for one helpful tag per day or per hour, it would be nice because sometimes there is just no saving a question with editing which will get me a +2.

EDIT:
And -1 for declined flags. Disputed flags are obviously neutral.

Comment: Please not. And IMO suggested edits should not earn someone rep too.

Comment: There is an incentive that exists.  Badges: (1) Citizen Patrol, (2) Deputy, (3) Marshal.

Comment: @juergend Well said.  Even if one argues that they should, suggested edits on a single post should __never__ earn more than 2.

Comment: I was not trying to say that they can edit and then close and get 4, I was trying to say that for helpful tags you get +1 because it's an incentive to clean up the site.

Comment: Suggested edits tend to become a nuisance, at times.  If flagging were to be rewarded with rep, it'd be a much bigger nuisance.

Comment: Only if declined flags cost reputation.

Comment: I didn't say they couldn't because honestly that would make it fair.

Answer (score 3):

No. Flagging show not be rewarded with more than the badges then there are now.

Why?

1. Every flag adds extra work for the relative small number of moderators.
2. Flagging is more serious then suggesting an edit. Flags should never be made too easy. An incentive in reputation might cause people to flag for the rep.

Comment: If the issue is the low amount of moderators then they either need to allow more people to become moderators, or allow users with at least a slightly lower rep to help.

Comment: This is an issue of trust. You can make anyone a mod, but I don't think that is good for the community.

Comment: But why is that bad for the community? Having more moderators (all elected) to have that power is not a trust issue.

Comment: @gabe Yeah, but if a bad (read: malicious) moderator gets elected, the consequences could be apocalyptic. So you can't really be too careful.

Comment: yes there is. Too careful meaning you trust no one and you loose the community. Agreed making moderators @1000 rep would be a bad idea but there are ways to make having more mods safer. ie: change logs with reverse capabilities for moderators

Comment: But while let all those mods spend there time in moderating? They could be helping someone out in the same time (and I personally think that is more fun / helpful to the community).

Comment: @gabe - More elected moderators is not the right way to approach this, for reasons I elaborate on here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185247/are-stack-overflow-mods-spending-enough-time-evaluating-each-flag/185264#185264 . Flags should be for exceptional circumstances. If we need to encourage more flags by incentivizing them with points (which we don't, given the volume and sometimes trivial nature of flags we see today), that indicates a problem elsewhere in the system that needs to be addressed. I want people to flag because they care about the site, not just to earn points.

Comment: Then flagging should be separated into 2 categories "community action" "moderator action", moderator action would be more aimed at complete deletion of things, community could be more aimed at fixing/relocating things, If you are saying that all the flags go to the moderators then agreed that's crazy. But then it should be separated so the moderators as you stated in the link are not being completely swamped.

Comment: @gabe: The flags are already split, since Vote to Close goes to 3K+ users. Custom flags go to mods. This only applies to questions and answers. Comments are always handled by mods. And there are a lot of those flags.

Answer (score 0):

There are already several incentives for flagging:

- First there are the flagging badges. (Citizen patrol, Deputy, Marshall)
- Second, if your number of helpful flags grows, your flags appear higher on the list so they can be handled earlier. (The reverse is also true).

Reputation should only be given for the primary purpose of the site (questions and answers).

Comment: Reputation is already not only given for questions and answers, though it is the primary, meta esk things like cleaning questions and flagging horrible questions should be incentivised. And of course bad flagging should be decentivised.

Comment: The only exception is suggested edits, and I don't like that either. But suggested edit rep is limited. And, as I said, flagging is already  encouraged.  (For fun, try to search meta for flag weight).

Comment: +1 and -1 are nearly nothing but it makes a user feel good about helping. where as badges are one time things and it's whatever after that.

Comment: Don't underestimate the value of the flag weight. If you flag a lot and they are marked as helpful, your flags rise to the top.

Comment: I can guarantee you, that if flagging results in rep changes, we need a lot more moderators. (And an asylum to get the old ones back on their feet).

Comment: Then I bring it back to my other point. Elect more moderators. This site is huge this should not be an issue.

Comment: In any case then it's annoying that they barely state that flags have weight. I did not even know that until I posted this question.

Comment: Ok, one of the ideas of SO is that the site is mostly self moderated (hence the reputation and the privileges). The elected diamond moderators are the human exception handlers.

Comment: I know that part but electing more than they do is not hard. They already have a vote of tons of users.

Comment: Flagweight was visible on the userpage, but this caused too many confusion (and a run to flag a lot in order to increase the flagweight)

Comment: Let's agree to disagree ;-).

Comment: Either let the user know about flag weight more, or make the user feel they are helping by incentivising.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that the flag weight is no longer used. Can't find the link right now though.

Comment: @user000001 the reference is spread through comments and partially related answers so it can be tough to find.  My answer on the subject is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195232/182513) which tried to pull some of those comments together.