# Incorrect link for FAQ on deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, help-center

When an answer is deleted, it says "Why was your post deleted? See the faq." with a link

> https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Which points to this FAQ page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions

Of course, the link should be to this page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now live on the production network.

Comment: brb, refreshing [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag/185075#185075). It still links to deleted-questions even though that's an answer.

Comment: Is it actually live? It still points to the wrong link on meta.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn meta is out of cycle at the moment because of the flags refactoring. Merges happen more slowly.

Comment: Ah OK. I assume that is related to the out-of-whack flag stats I've been seeing on my meta profile as well.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is in place, and you get taken to the right content, so this isn't urgent to fix. I plan to update all post notices, error messages, etc. that refer to the FAQ at some point, but there are quite a few to change and it may take a while for us to get to all of them. Thanks for bearing with us.