# How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?

Tags: support, faq, flags, answers, not-an-answer

- What is the "Not an Answer" flag and what is its purpose?
- When should I use this flag?
- When should I not use this flag?
- But I'm still not sure if I'm using the flag correctly...
- An answer is "Not an Answer", but the flag was declined or disputed!
- The flag was marked helpful, but the answer wasn't deleted!

**See also:** [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 74):

### What is the "not an answer" flag and what is its purpose?

The "not an answer" flag is a moderator flag that users can raise to notify moderators and privileged users<sup>1</sup> that a posted answer does not make an attempt to answer the question, and should be deleted.

### When should I use this flag?

Use this flag when an answer is:

- Asking a new question
- Clarifying the existing question
- Communicating with another user
- Saying "thanks" or confirming that another posted answer worked for them
- "Bumping" the question, as in "I have the same problem, have you found a solution?"
- Not attempting to address the question asked in any way

### When should I not use this flag?

Do not use this flag when:

- The user posts a partial answer to the issues presented in the question
- The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it
- The problem with the answer is subtle and would benefit from additional explanation (see below)

### But I'm still not sure if I'm using the flag correctly...

If it is *blatantly* obvious to you that what you're looking at meets the above conditions for using the flag, you're probably using the flag correctly.

**If the problem is subtle** and may not be obvious to whoever reviews your flag, then consider raising an *"in need of moderator intervention"* flag instead, and explain in detail why you think the answer violates the site rules and should thus be removed.

### An answer is "Not an Answer", but the flag was declined or disputed!

First, verify that the problem wasn't corrected after you raised the flag. If the author or someone else was able to edit the answer and fix the problem, then you did nothing wrong; the problem simply ceased to be visible at the time the flag was handled.

If the problem is still visible, then consider that perhaps it isn't as obvious as you thought it was. When reviewing "not an answer" flags, moderators aren't shown the question or comments in context without clicking further, which they probably won't do unless there's an *obvious* reason to look for additional context. The same applies to flags handled in the review queue for privileged users<sup>1</sup>, which requires reviewers to scroll or click through to view the question or other answers.

As suggested above, subtle problems can be more effectively handled by raising an *"in need of moderator intervention"* flag, which allows you to explain the problem in detail. If a "not an answer" flag is declined or disputed and a serious problem is still evident, then escalate the issue to the moderator team with a detailed description.

### The flag was marked helpful, but the answer wasn't deleted!

There are four possible cases:

- A moderator found your flag borderline and decided not to delete the answer, but didn't want to penalize you by declining your flag.
- Your flag sent the answer to community review (see <sup>1</sup> below), and:

  - One of the reviewers opted to edit the answer. This dismissed the review task and marked your flag "helpful". Or:
  - The reviewers agreed with you and voted to delete the answer (marking your flag helpful), but:

    - The author later undeleted it, or:
    - The answer had a positive score. Answers with positive scores can't be deleted by community members, so an outcome in favor of deletion will instead forward the answer to moderators for further review.

In the first and last cases above, a moderator will have already seen or will see the situation and has already or will soon handle it. In other cases, if the problem wasn't fixed, flag the answer using the "in need of moderator intervention" option and clearly explain the issue.

You can see which situation of the above happened by clicking through to the post's timeline, which will link to the community reviews (if any) the answer went through, as well as show its deletion history. If there's no entry for a community review, the flag was processed manually by a moderator.

---

<sup>1</sup> The "not an answer" flag will trigger the answer to be reviewed by members of the site with editing privileges via the *Low quality posts* review queue (named *Low quality answers* on sites with the *Triage* queue) if the answer has never been to that queue before. If the answer ends up in this queue, the flag will still be able to be processed by moderators after a [delay that varies per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/377214) (15 minutes on most main Q&A sites, 60 minutes on some large sites including Stack Overflow, and no delay on meta sites). If the answer has already been reviewed in that queue before, this flag can only be handled by moderators.

Comment: "Do not use this flag when a user posts: [...] An answer to a (slightly) different question". What if it's an entirely different question? Like advice about handling [tag:strings] for a question about [tag:image-processing]?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/is-it-appropriate-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-if-it-doesnt-address-the

Comment: @RobertHarvey This may still be [overly restrictive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288541/1858225); the specific case in that link *may* arguably fall under "communicate with another user," but it's not a good fit. Perhaps another bullet item should be "Discuss the topic at hand without actually providing an answer", or something?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Is there the smallest of doubts?  If there is, use a custom flag instead.  Don't use NAA unless it is crystal-clear.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Personally, I have (literally) no doubt that the example in the linked meta question was *not an answer*, and was therefore appropriately flagged as such, but obviously some reviewers disagree, and it's unclear (to me) why that is.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Can you look at that "answer" and evaluate whether or not it is an answer *without looking at the question?*

Comment: @KyleStrand: That said, I can see why it was flagged NAA, although you do have to squint a bit.  Sometimes mods get it wrong; you'll never get one hundred percent accuracy, especially on a flag that people where argued about its meaning for literally years.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Without looking at the question, you can tell that either it's not an answer, or the question itself is off-topic for SO, because the only question I can imagine for which that "answer" is an *answer* would be something like "why doesn't the API for [some Apple product or OS] provide volume control that fits [some specific need]?" That's more of a discussion question than a solve-this-programming-problem question.

Comment: I guess I've been implicitly assuming that when evaluating flags on answers, one should assume that the answer itself is probably on-topic, but I realize that might not be a good assumption.

Comment: @KyleStrand: If you really need an absolute barometer, then fall back on the things that are specifically identified as Not an Answer: an attempt to communicate with another user, an attempt to ask a new question, an attempt to bump the existing question, a clarification made by the OP that belongs in the question itself, or a statement like "Thanks" or "This worked for me."   If it's not one of those things, then really it's better to explain the problem to the moderator specifically, in a custom flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/843/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Do not use this flag if you have to consider the question to determine if it is not an answer? :o How would you know if it is not an answer if you cannot look at the question it was supposed to answer? Example: Answer: "Donald Trump is the President of USA at the moment of writing this comment.". Can you tell me if it is an answer or not? I won't tell you the question I have in mind, because that seems to be your point.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 I believe by the standard defined in this post, what you quoted _is_ an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you please explain why you rolled back that edit in whole?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: because Braiam has misunderstood what the NAA flag is for, and has been trying to convince the rest of the world that their interpretation of the wrong help page applies to the NAA flag. They [then tried to use their edit here to claim authority](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#comment594278_265553). Their edit was wrong here, as was their edit on the SO faq post on the subject, so I rolled it back.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: I had not otherwise considered there was anything worth keeping in that edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the rollback. I'd have done it sooner had I noticed the original edit.

Comment: I'd like to propose removing the third bullet point under when not to use the flag and the final paragraph about mods not being able to see everything - it seems to me to just be discouraging people from properly flagging in order to justify lazy mods. On many sites in the network there aren't so many flags that the mods shouldn't be expected to check the context when needed.

Comment: @curiousdannii: That's a pretty bold statement.  May I offer a counterpoint?  Users have micro-managed this flag to the point where it's almost lost its meaning.  The flag is incredibly simple to understand: *use it when someone is using the answer space to do something other than post an answer.*  Your accusation of mod laziness is unfounded; Not an Answer flags can be dispatched in about six seconds if they're used properly.  If a mod has to open the extended view to figure out why you flagged, it takes about 10 times as long.  It's not the mods that are being lazy.

Comment: @Robert Nothing changes from the mod's perspective if someone writes a custom flag saying it's NAA. They'll still have to check the context. So I just don't see the sense in recommending people not use the standard flag.

Comment: @curiousdannii: You can flag however you like.  But if you cast an NAA flag where a custom one would have been more appropriate (against the advice of a mod who's been doing this for years), and I can't work out why you think the post you're flagging isn't an answer, then I can't help you.

Comment: @Robert Sure but most of the time it's straight forward to the mods who check context. Mods who refuse to ever check the context of flags surely must be such a small minority that they don't warrant changing the advice of how to flag as this post does.

Comment: @curiousdannii: This isn't a change in advice; it's been the way I've described for years.  The whole point of having a custom flag is to give people the ability to provide the necessary context *within the flag itself.*  I never said we don't check context; what I said was  "don't make this harder than it has to be."

Comment: @RobertHarvey But then doesn't a custom flag bypass the community review process?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please note there is now a discussion about this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310638/should-a-custom-flag-be-used-instead-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-when-the-answer

Answer (score 38):

## What is the *not an answer* flag?

The *not an answer* flag (NAA) is a flag to indicate that **someone used the "answer the question" box to post something that isn't really an answer.** It usually pushes an answer to the low-quality queue, where its fate is decided by reviewers. If it stays there for too long, the answer is also shown to diamond moderators in their flag queue. If the flag is considered valid, the post is deleted.

## When *should* I use this flag?

Use this flag when an answer is being used to:

- Ask a new question
- Clarify the existing question
- Communicate with another user
- Say "thanks," or confirm that another posted answer worked for him.
- "Bump" the question, as in "I have the same problem, have you found a solution?"

## When *may* I use this flag?

You can also use this flag for the following reasons, *if you include a comment below the answer explaining the specific problem:*

- **[link-only answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/255554)**, i.e., answers that become totally worthless when you remove all URLs. Note that a short answer that mostly is a link can still be an answer, if the actual text is useful; it usually is a bad answer though. For example, the following can still be an answer (to the right question):

  > Consider the [`blobfish` module](https://example.com/cgi-bin/docs/html/blobf.html).  It solves the problem you're describing.

  The following is a link-only answer:

  > Take a look at https://example.com/cgi-bin/docs/html/blobf.html
- answers that attempt to **answer another question** or are just a general **dump of unsolicited information**, for example:

  > Question: What is the capital of Brazil?
  >
  > Not an answer 1: The capital of Argentina is Buenos Aires.
  >
  > Not an answer 2: Brazil is a state in South America.
  >
  > Not an answer 3: We went to Brazil for our honeymoon.
- **obviously dishonest answers** to the question. Most of these are also [not nice](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and should thus be flagged as rude or abusive or with a custom flag. But sometimes they are just a well-intentioned, but bad joke, e.g.:

  > Question: What’s the difference between *affect* and *effect?*
  >
  > Answer: The first letter.
- **answers violating site-specific requirements on answers**.
  A typical example are sites requiring answers (or answers to certain questions) to be backed up with sources.
  In that case, unsourced answers can be regarded as not an answer.
  You can see it this way: On such sites, the request for sources is implicit in every question and thus unsourced answers do not address the question.
  Be sure to familiarise with a site’s specific guidelines before using the flag this way.

## Rules of Thumb

If you can’t determine whether or not it’s an answer *without looking at the question* it supposedly answers, explain the problem in a comment below the answer.

If you need knowledge that goes deeper than a basic expertise of the site’s topic (e.g., knowledge of a specific programming language on SO) don't use an NAA flag.

## When should I not use this flag?

Do not use the *not an answer* flag for:

- **partial or short answers**. If an answer addresses the question and is at least one small step forward regarding the problem at hand (and more than a link), it’s not NAA. Don’t listen to people who claim that these should be comments. The fundamental distinction between answers and comments is that the former seek to address the question and the latter try to improve the question – not length.
- **wrong answers**. Downvote them and use comments to explain what is wrong. The NAA flag is for answers that are *not even wrong,* i.e., they do not even live on the right–wrong axis (for the respective question).
- **plagiarism**. Answers which are just *verbatim* copies of previously existing answers, or other sources, without attribution should be flagged with a custom moderator flag and the situation explained, including a link to where you think the copy was made from.
- **duplicate answers**. Answers added which *only* repeat a point made in a *long-existing* answer without adding *anything* worthwhile to it should be flagged with a custom moderator flag which explains the issue and links to the answer which you feel is the source. This almost only applies to short answers which show an egregious lack of awareness of previous answers. Longer answers often offer a different explanation or presentation of the facts which is worthwhile. Answers which were posted only minutes apart are not flaggable merely because they cover the same points. Such an answer *may* be flaggable if there is *clear* plagiarism (i.e. it's a direct copy and paste with, at most, minimal differences).
- **spam, rude, or abusive posts**. Use the respective flag instead, as it ensures a quick and proper handling. Note that gibberish can be flagged as abusive when the author has no other positive contributions to the site, but the benefit of doubt should be granted to users who have other positive contributions (i.e. flag gibberish from such accounts as NAA, unless such posts are repeated).

Comment: Note: This new answer originated from a discussion between moderators and is separate to allow review. I am aware that it disagrees with the old answer on some matters. That’s the point.

Comment: So each moderator has a different view of how to use the NAA flag. Not confusing at all for the ordinary users who should use the flag, at the end of the day.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That’s not what I meant. This answer is intended to replace the existing one. However since it’s almost completely written from scratch and changes some important aspects, I did not just want to replace the old answer, but leave this here for others to review first. The aforementioned discussion ended mostly in agreement and included the other answer’s author.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Technically all that's needed is for the mods on *each site* to agree on how to use the NaA flag ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor mods don't *use* the flag, just *handle* it. If users won't know how to use it, it would be a problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Damn the 5-minute window on comment edits ... s/`how to use the NaA flag`/`how the NaA flag should be used`.

Comment: @randal'thor: I would expect that a considerable portion of these flags gets handled by reviewers on most sites.

Comment: Also, how is this different from [this post by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)? So many different views, it's really impossible to know how to flag.

Comment: "answers that attempt to answer another question or are just a general dump of unsolicited information, for example:" This is misleading at best on SO for one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/ where the [prevailing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question/308459#comment260813_308441) _ex post facto_ definition of "an answer" is ["anything that anyone manages to post in the answer box"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314395/is-a-self-answer-of-looks-like-i-had-a-typo-really-not-naa/314400#comment305649_314395).

Comment: Not to say that _I_ disagree with this answer, but a lot of other people do.

Comment: *how is this different from this post by Shog?* – That’s not a FAQ and mostly about link-only answers. I do not see any disagreement here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The answer in the first link was written by the author of the other answer to this question, hence the above comments apply. — The conclusion of the Meta post in the second link seems to align with this answer. I do not know which comment you wanted to refer to since the link is broken. — The third link is about an SO-specific problem with answers that only make sense on delete-worthy questions. — Also keep in mind that “answers that attempt to answer another question” agrees with the wording of the flag itself: “does not attempt to answer **the** question.”

Comment: Sorry about the broken link (for some reason `q` instead of `questions` doesn't work for a comment URL); it was to the first comment on the "Fifth Element" question, "It is an attempt to answer _a_ question..." And while I agree with you and this answer, the upvotes on Meta answers saying "these are non-answers" don't seem to affect the way the flags are actually handled.

Comment: While I like a lot of this, the requirement that reviewers and moderators have to read comments to understand why something was flagged isn't going to work in practice. "not an answer" flags should be obvious without requiring additional context, so anything that isn't clear when reading the answer by itself should most likely be placed in a custom flag. For that reason, the "duplicate answer" and "answering a different question" examples will most likely not be processed correctly if flagged as "not an answer". I'd recommend removing those and the wording about leaving comments.

Comment: @BradLarson: And that’s the crux that lead to all this: What you say may apply to SO and maybe some other big sites (and I totally understand this), but it’s a bad idea for many other sites. Also, it goes totally against the wording of the question (at least for answers to a different question).

Comment: You say that a duplicate answer is NAA, but the other moderator asks not to consider other answers to decide NAA. You further make it confusing by posting comments that this is an updated version of another answer you posted earlier. The only other answer here is the one posted by another moderator. Is that the one you are referring to? You moderator guys might want to come to an agreement among yourself first, and update your answers  (and *delete* the obsolete ones) to avoid confusing users.

Comment: @MaskedMan: Yes I am referring to the other answer. This endeavour got a little bit lost. I will take steps towards a resolution. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I re-read my comment again, and now it sounds like a complaint. Sorry for that, it wasn't intended to sound that way.

Comment: @MaskedMan: I see nothing wrong with complaining about this situation.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "So each moderator has a different view of how to use the NAA flag. Not confusing at all for the ordinary users who should use the flag, at the end of the day." No, moderators deliberately choose to ignore the help center when it says "How do I write a good answer? [...] **Answer the question** Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative."

Comment: @Braiam dunno about that. Fact is, there are now two different answers here to the same question, and each based on personal opinions of moderators.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd which is what *should not* happen. If anything the faq should further nail down the specifics working of what the help center says. Like "what happens when I flag" or "on what queue would my flag be handled".

Comment: @Braiam not sure I follow. So you also prefer to have only one answer here on this faq? If so, how you suggest to do that?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I suggest that we start by the help center. And expand from there. If you have a structure that defines in broad strokes the policies, it would be very difficult to that you would get so diverging answers.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: This is a nice effort, but it suffers from a critical flaw.  All of the reasons you've cited when you  *may* use the flag are more suitable for a **custom moderator flag.**  Instead of making mods hunt for comments that might pertain to your flag, just cast a custom flag and put your explanation there.  To be crystal clear, *if the flag requires additional explanation of any kind, use a custom moderator flag.*

Comment: @Robert that's not a critical flaw, and if everyone followed your advice then the majority of flags on many sites would have to be custom flags. I don't know which sites you moderate, but what you're saying is not applicable to all.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I moderate Stack Overflow, where thousands of flags are cast every day, and I'm telling you that what you're saying is simply not true.  I honestly don't understand why people are so committed to the idea that they need to do this in a different way than how the system is designed.  SE gave users a custom flag option so that they can provide the necessary context for their flag to be handled properly, but you don't want to use it.  Why?

Comment: @Robert because other than this community written post on MSE, nothing suggests to the user as they go about their flagging that the NAA flag should only be used for what is blatantly obvious. Users should be trusted to flag responsibly, and aside from SO and maybe a few other high traffic sites, using the NAA flag is responsible.

Comment: @curiousdannii: You're arguing assertions I didn't make.  I never said it had to be blatantly obvious, I said that the custom moderator flag is there to provide any necessary context.  The community has legislated the NAA flag ad nauseum on several metas, but its true purpose remains simple and clear: *use it when someone is using the answer space for something other than posting an answer.*  It's not meant to handle marginal answers of any kind, which is what the center section of your post suggests.

Comment: @Robert this isn't my post, though I do agree with most of it. There's absolutely nothing marginal about posts which answer another question, though evaluating that often involves reading the body (not just the title) of the question, which is why I still can't make sense of your advice.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Here's how you make sense of it.  The "When ***may*** you use this flag" section of this post all applies to *answers,* not *non-answers.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There is one major problem with your suggestion: A huge amount of NAA flags aren’t handled by moderators but by the community ([statistics for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation)). Custom flags cannot be handled by the community.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I see.  So the user community is essentially trying to bend the NAA flag to its will.  There are probably better solutions than trying to co-opt a flag for something other than its intended purpose.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I could equally claim that you are trying to bend the NAA flag to your will. For example, the flag description clearly says “it does not attempt to answer **the** question. Anyway, with the current answer-flagging system, we can only have makeshift solutions. What we need are proper answer-deletion reasons.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: You didn't quote the part of that verbiage that is most critical: *"It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."*  The reasons for an NAA flag are specifically enumerated in the flag description.  And yes, we need proper flags for these things.

Comment: *The reasons for an NAA flag are specifically enumerated in the flag description.* – and the comes *deleted altogether,* which is rather unspecific and captures a lot of things.