# Asking questions in the Answer just to get the first spot

Tags: discussion, reputation, etiquette, not-an-answer, fastest-gun

I've seen this a few times now on StackOverflow, instead of using the comments to ask for additional information, a user will add an answer asking their questions.

Then, when they get the information they were looking for, they'll edit their answer.  This makes it appear as if they were the first to actually answer the question, which, in my opinion, is a bit fraudulent.

I suppose if ultimately the answer they provide is correct, it's still helping the user out which is the main intent of the site, but if it's not correct they simply delete the answer and walk away.

Is there anything those of us who follow the etiquette rules can/should do when we see this type of behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you see a request for clarification posted as an answer, flag it as "Not an answer", because it's not an answer.  It is likely to be deleted by a mod rather quickly.

If you feel that an answer is not helpful, say because it is abusing the answer feature to post non-answers, you are free to downvote said answer and/or comment on the answer (politely, and constructively) indicating that it is a violation of the site's rules.

Comment: This makes sense... however, I've also found that downvoting these people makes them mad and they downvote any answers you might have given as well.  Silly, really, but that's how they play the game.

Comment: @Donovan Hence why I make it clear that that is optional, where the flagging is something that you really should do every time.

Comment: @Donovan Serial downvoting is dealt with (a script is run to check if any user is serial upvoting/downvoting, and then corrects the rep gained/lost from it.)

Comment: I will start flagging when I see it, thanks for the info.  :)

Comment: @hichris123 What was just described wouldn't be serial downvoting though.  If the user went to your profile and downvoted a ton of posts, sure, but the described situation of that user revenge downvoting just the one answer to that same question, despite it being a helpful answer, won't be reversed, as it's not serial voting.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't agree more.

It annoys the whatsits out of me.

I and other decent users are bashing it out in the question's comments asking questions to direct the questioner to either the answer or what might be the answer, and someone comes along and posts an answer like:

> Why is X like that? If because of Y then you should do Z

Usually one or two pathetic sentences.

That is nothing more than full of presumption with suggested option(s) based entirely on presumption disguised as an answer.
This would have been perfect in the question's comments as a question, as they're intended for, then when the questioner answers they then have the valid info for an actual answer.

But the most annoying thing which happens is the OP questioner then engages in discussion within the (bad) answer's comments, usually giving the (naughty) answerer most of the control of the entire question, as more often than not, the questioner no longer bothers with the comments on the question's comments as they have a one-on-one coder on hand replying directly to sort their problem quickly.

As the comments on the answer ensue, the answerer usually finds the issue, edits his answer, questioner upvotes and accepts their answer and a few "chummy" comments follow - I've seen, even on bad questions and answers, where the questioner say "thanks I've upvoted and accepted" and the answerer reply with "thanks I've upvoted your question".

While it can be argued that the questioner got their answer and it's there for other visitors with the same issue, there are other users affected here - users who spend time in comments first as they're supposed to trying help people out.
So the poor sods who have read through a mammoth block of the question's badly structured code, with all sorts of cringeworthy issues, just to try to help them out end up wasting their time.

That said, (rant over) in general I think that while this issue happens and is *very* annoying, the flags and votes usually sort this sort of behaviour out enough that it's not frequent enough to be a real issue (from what I've seen anyway).

The site, flagging, comments and answering works very well, it's the users who spoil it.
If users did the right thing, in the above scenario, a decent questioner would have downvoted the crap answer as *it does not help them* and continued with the users trying to help in the question's comments.
And so they should as it's often the case that comments in the question's comment area are from knowledgeable users who give decent answers, usually still in the comment area as they're happy just to help out.

As Servy said, flag it. If more people did this more often then the few bits of crap would be thinned out and people (at least some) would get the message.

Comment: I agree, as quite a new user on SO, I enjoy trying to help people out. Often I'm composing a detailed answer only for someone else to shoot in first with a question which could have been found if they had read the question a little more first... When that happens I don't even bother posting, just go and try to help someone else instead.

Comment: Yeah it is annoying. Tho, as said, I think it's fairly rare, certainly infrequent enough that it's not worth tackling it. Just wish more people would downvote and flag.

Comment: Indeed, it's frustrating and this "gaming the system" by some users takes a bit of the fun out of the site.  What I've found works _sometimes_ is to go ahead and complete your answer, give greater detail and explanation.  More often than not, this additional time taken is rewarded by the OP.