# Username still showing old name on a question

Tags: discussion, bug, users

From what I know, changing your username will change it everywhere but looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag), Robert Harvey ♦'s name is still showing as The Grinch as the name of the question OP.

[image]

It is also still showing as The Grinch on the question in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=newest.

[image]

Is there a reason for this or this a bug?

Comment: Seems like this is [Status-bugbydesign]