# What to do if my flag on answer, that is obviously invalid, is disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags

I am an active member on Stack Overflow and usually love to read all the questions and answers to improve my programming skills.

Recently I found an invalid answer and flagged that answer as *Not an  Answer* but it was disputed.

So main question is,
**Is there any procedure where the user who flagged the answer will be given some hint (comments) as to why that flag is being disputed so that flagging can be improved ?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753886/1686291) is an example, I flagged this answer as "Not an answer" because this one is wrong. but flag was disputed without any comments.!!

Comment: Can you post the example ?

Comment: [What is a Disputed flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/216721) and [Proper use of Not an Answer flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/216721). These 2 questions should answer all your doubts.

Comment: This is my first meta post. so downvoters please suggest improvements.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ for first question ? hints for being disputed ?

Comment: The answer you flagged as "Not an Answer" is probably a bad answer or a wrong answer, but it is indeed an answer. That is why your "Not an Answer" flag was declined

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar - If your flag was declined by a moderator, they might provide a small note as to why it was declined, but in case of a disputed flag, AFAIK, there is no note which would be given as to why it was disputed, because, in general, disputed flags are *considered to be neither helpful nor declined*.

Comment: Not an answer include "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question." so i thought this one is correct for wrong answer...
can you indicate which flag to use for incorrect one ? @Ɍ.Ɉ

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar - You need not flag the wrong/incorrect answers. That is what downvotes are for. If you feel that an answer is wrong, downvote it and move on. :)

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar if the question is "what is 1+1" then "7" is an answer even though it's wrong, and "how do you get to Picadilly Circus from here?" is not an answer. If you flag the equivalent of "7" it will be disputed or declined for sure. Just downvote those.

Answer (score 1):

Disputed flags in two lines:

- If the mods agree with you, then your flag will be marked as disputed (because you disagreed with the original flagger).
- If the mods disagree with you then it will be disputed as well! (because you disagreed with the mods)