# Why was this flag disputed?

Tags: support, flags, specific-question, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751713/1686291) as `not an answer` because this one should be a comment as per Stack Overflow regulations.

Even though the flag was disputed, I can not find any comments from the mod who disputed the flag. Earlier today I asked a question about [commenting why flag is being disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221090/251720) but I cannot find a proper reason.

Can anyone explain the reason please? So that I can improve my flagging...

Comment: You did find http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag?rq=1

Comment: I can not find "commenting the reason why it was disputed..."

Comment: [I did try to explain it to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221090/what-if-helpful-flag-is-disputed-reviews-of-mod-for-disputed-flag#comment717599_221090) atleast how much ever I knew and gave you [links to questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221090/what-if-helpful-flag-is-disputed-reviews-of-mod-for-disputed-flag#comment717591_221090) you should read to know about the flags and their usages.

Comment: Yes i got it what is disputing, but can not understand in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21751713/1686291) one !!!

Comment: It is a low quality answer  but still qualifies as an answer. A downvote would be enough

Comment: If the poster had phrased that as an answer rather than a question, it would have been an answer (although a poor one). I guess that's why at least one mod disagreed with the flag.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar - The flag was disputed, which means, atleast 1 of the 10k+ users felt that the flag was wrong and hence, pressed the *Invalid Flags* option they possess when reviewing the flags. As to that user felt it was an invalid flag, Barth has already conveyed that in the comment previous to this.

Comment: I find these types of flags to be very contradicting often. Sometimes they're considered appropriate, sometimes they aren't without a clear distinction between the two. Keep in mind as well that 'disputed' doesn't mean you are wrong necessarily: it means at least one other reviewer deemed it invalid.

Comment: Regarding your [previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221090/251720): An incorrect answer is still an answer. Such answers should not be flagged as 'not an answer'. Just downvote/comment them.

Comment: The answer you flagged as "not an answer" *is* an answer, as others have already said. You could had used a different flag, comment or edit it to improve it. I think the primary purpose here is to help one another, not just flag answers/questions around. Flag it if it cannot be edited, but *improving* the answer should be the primary concern, in my opinion, not flagging it. Downvoting without first commenting the poster to improve it does not help, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw this "Not An Answer" flag in the review queue yesterday and I marked it as an "Invalid Flag" which lead to it being disputed.

While I agree that the quality of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751713/426671) is not the best (since it is phrased as a question) it is still an answer because it directs the OP to a possible solution to their question by suggesting that they try something.

If the answer had said something like:

> *I am having the same problem and I tried java.text.NumberFormat and it is still not working.*

Then you could flag that as "Not An Answer".

If you feel that the quality of the existing answer is lacking, then you can downvote or comment - flagging it as "Not An Answer" will lead to a declined or disputed result.

Comment: I flagged that because i thought it should be an comment !!! which fits to the "not an answer" as explained..."It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether."

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar Well I disagree which is why I marked the flag as invalid, while it might not be the best answer it is still an answer, they are suggesting a possible solution to the problem.

Comment: I was confused because same thing occurred with my answer when i was newer to the forum. Thanks you for posting your views.