# Why was a useful answer that clarified the use case of the question deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

In this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/how-to-test-if-a-string-is-a-vim-command), there is a comment asking the **motivation/use case** of the question.

So I (who asked the question) added an answer to clarify that.

But unfortunately, it was deleted, under the reason of

> answers should only be used for answers

My question is: *should it be deleted???*

Comment: The usual thing to do would be to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it should be. But it **not** the usual case IMO. Few people like a question with 80+ lines of code, thus why I make it a separate answer instead, in the spirit of help some read the post.

Comment: Did what you post as an answer give an answer to your question? No? Then it isn't an answer and should be deleted.

Comment: how you see the reason for a deleted comment?

Comment: In opinion, the spirit of stackexchange is to help the community, I post the answer to hope someone later read the post get some **motivation/use case of the question itself**.

Comment: @qeatzy if you made that comment to clarify the question, go on edit the question itself instead of commenting

Comment: And I think this kind of **blindly delete useful answers just for the intactness of fixed rules** is not wise at all, and is rather harmful.

Comment: Or, should I edit the question instead, to make the answer relevant directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

Comment: Honestly, don't see what the problem is here @qeatzy. Your question was answered, satisfactorily (I presume since you accepted the answer). What's the point of doing anything to salvage the removed non-answer?

Comment: The point is **answering question is not the whole thing**. The deleted answer clarify **why** it being asked. What I value `stackoverflow.com` most is not just see answers and over, but rather besides that, explore **why the question arise**, and many expand to **related context, similar cases** but not the same question per se.

Comment: Well then, if you feel that strongly about it, you should start a discussion on Meta Vi and Vim. The site's community is far better equipped than the Meta SE crowd to evaluate the merits of your answer.

Comment: Or maybe users in similar cases just choose to not answer question actively in the future, just to not waste effort and time. Though, I won't, in this time, at least.

Comment: Thx, I may choose to discuss there later.

Comment: I didn't know there is meta for each site, sorry for that.

Comment: @qeatzy If you think that it's important for the question to explain why it is asking the question it is, then *include that in the question*.  It doesn't belong as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it should be deleted.

These sites are Q&A sites, not traditional discussion forums. The answers section is strictly reserved for answers. Anything that doesn't actually answer the question doesn't belong there - even if it's helpful.

You can respond to clarification requests either by updating your question or by posting a comment.

You may find more details in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help):

- [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I have read the second post, and not see any rules that specific answer offended.

Comment: @qeatzy "Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed."

Comment: Yeah, that depends on how is **fundamentally** is interpreted.

Comment: And I thinks many people will thinks it answers the question somehow, not to mention the harm to the commuity to delete **useful answers**.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have anything to add here @qeatzy. Let's agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: And I **indeed** have see too many answer that do not answer the original question per se, but add valuable component to it, at `stackoverflow.com`, and many other sites.

Comment: @qeatzy So how are you interpreting your post as an answer that "fundamentally answers the question"?  You've said yourself that it's not trying to answer the question, so how are you interpreting that statement as not applying?   The community also didn't delete a useful *answer*, it deleted something that *wasn't an answer at all*.  If you think it would make a useful addition to the question then *add it to the question*.

Comment: @qeatzy - The community decides how it is interpreted if 5 separate people determine a question/answer should be deleted there is a good chance there is a problem with that question/answer.  The community decides if an answer is useful, if its being deleted, that is a signal that it perhaps needed work and should be improved and be flagged to be restored (after it's improved).

Comment: "And I indeed have see too many answer that do not answer the original question per se, but add valuable component to it" - Sounds like those answers should have been deleted because, they did not answer the question that was asked, commentary should not be submitted as an answer.  Which is what these answers you describe actually are, commentary, and commentary shouldn't be submitted as an answer.