# Add "more information" field when flagging

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I am generally flagging a post, I want to include more information for the people who are reviewing my flag. However, the only way I can add my two cents to it is to flag it for moderator intervention which is obviously not the proper usage of that flag. Can we have a little entry field that pops up after you select a radio button when flagging so that you can include more information about your *specific* flag?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog - I see what you're saying, but I'm saying for _all_ flags which makes it different.

Comment: Adding more information to a "not an answer" flag is also addressed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag, and the same also applies to "very low quality" flags.

Comment: You can always leave a comment.